# How to remove repeated data from the result of joins of 2 different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, database-administration

There are 3 tables in my database, these are the following:

**1. table1 (po)**

```
po_id   other_col_data
  1       other col data
  2       other col data
  3       other col data
  4       other col data
  5       other col data
  6       other col data
```

**2. table2 (po_items)**

```
      po_id   |poitems  |amount          
      ========+=======+==========      
      1       |aaaa   |200             
      1       |bbbbb  |150             
      2       |ccccc  |50              
      2       |ddddd  |250  
      3       |eeeee  |325
      3       |fffff  |520 
      3       |ggggg  |120
```

**3. table3 (inv_items)**

```
      po_id   |invitems|amount          
      ========+=======+==========      
      1       |aaaa   |200             
      1       |bbbbb  |150             
      1       |ccccc  |50              
      2       |ddddd  |250  
      3       |eeeee  |325
      3       |fffff  |520 
      3       |ggggg  |120
      1       |ccccc  |50              
      2       |ddddd  |250  
      3       |eeeee  |325
      1       |kkkkk  |50              
      2       |ddddd  |250  
      3       |eeeee  |325
```

and I want to result in below format:

**Result**

```
  ID   ITEM   PO-Amount INV-Amount
    ====+======+==========+==========  
    1    aaaaa  200       200
    1    aaaaa  150       150 
    1    ccccc  00        50
    1    kkkkk  00        50
```

Comment: ...and _(I assume)_ you have no idea how to write the SQL? Correct?

Comment: Have you attempted any queries to solve this problem?

Comment: SELECT po.id, poi.item_description, poi.amount AS POI_AMOUNT, inv.amount AS INV_AMOUNT
FROM purchase_orders AS po
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items AS poi ON po.id = poi.purchase_order_id
INNER JOIN invoice_items AS inv ON po.id = inv.purchase_order_id
WHERE inv.purchase_order_id = poi.purchase_order_id

Comment: But this query will return all the items from po_items table... and the problem is that, if the item is not exist in the invoice table in that situation at the inv_amount column repeat the previous amount for that particular item...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
po_items.po_id AS ID,
if(po_items.poitems = 'NULL' or po_items.poitems = '', inv_items.invitems, po_items.poitems) AS ITEM,
ifnull(po_items.amount,0) AS PO-AMOUNT,
ifnull(inv_items.amount,0) AS INV-AMOUNT
FROM po_items
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_items ON po_items.po_id = inv_items.po_id
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
po_items.po_id AS ID,
if(po_items.poitems = 'NULL' or po_items.poitems = '', inv_items.invitems, po_items.poitems) AS ITEM,
ifnull(po_items.amount,0) AS PO-AMOUNT,
ifnull(inv_items.amount,0) AS INV-AMOUNT
FROM po_items
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_items ON po_items.po_id = inv_items.po_id
WHERE inv.purchase_order_id = poi.purchase_order_id;
```

Comment: SELECT po.id, poi.item_description, poi.amount AS POI_AMOUNT, inv.amount AS INV_AMOUNT
FROM purchase_orders AS po
INNER JOIN purchase_order_items AS poi ON po.id = poi.purchase_order_id
INNER JOIN invoice_items AS inv ON po.id = inv.purchase_order_id
WHERE inv.purchase_order_id = poi.purchase_order_id

Comment: I am also used this same query it will return all the items from po table not from both of the tables... and I am also unable to ignore repeatation of the INV_Amount...

Comment: So first thing is that I want all the unique items fetching from both of the tables and if amount available in both of the tables then show, if not available in one of them, then show 0 or NULL or blank, But I don't want repetition of previous amount there...  It will help you to understood my problem...

Comment: From what I understand from your requirement, pl try the query that I edited above in my answer.

Comment: I tried it... but it gives the same result as previous.. no change found in the result.

Comment: Full Outer Join doesn't work in mysql..  **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN invoice_items as inv_items ON po_items.purchase_order_id = inv_i' at line 7**

Comment: I Try the edited code, but its not working. Its not showing INV ITEMS